# Script works without jQuery UI, but not with the jQuery UI selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I, as a newbie to JS, created a very simple script to show and hide the "disabled" function in an select menu.

Everything works fine, untill i load jQuery UI for the selectmenu. Then it doesn't work anymore.

I tried all day to solve it, but can't. Perhaps anyone could help me out.

```
// Metadata
$('#year').change(function(){
    var sel = $(this); 
    var val = sel.val();

    if(val == "2008")
    {
         $('#c2').find("option:eq(1)").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#c2').find("option:eq(1)").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }

});
```

What should be happening is that when anyone selects "2008" from #year, it should enable option 1 in #c2 and visa versa.

It seems possible [here](http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/tests/visual/selectmenu/disabled.html), but I am not able to bend the script down to my own piece of trial and error.

**Updated code**

```
<script>
// Metadata
$("#year").selectmenu({

    // listen to the select event of the custom menu, not the original dropdown
    select: function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

       if(val == "2008"){
             $("#c2").find("option:eq(2)").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#c2").find("option:eq(2)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        // must call this to reflect the change
        $("#c2").selectmenu("refresh");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If I'm reading their source code correctly, you need to call selectmenu("refresh") after making a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the demo page you linked, it appears that it is necessary to update selectmenu by calling its refresh method.

Example from the demo source:

```
files2.find("option:eq(0)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
files2.selectmenu("refresh"); // <-- this
```

I think that this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/zuXSU/2/. When I change the menu, one of the options enables/disables.

### Relevant Code

```
$("#year").selectmenu({

    // listen to the select event of the custom menu, not the original dropdown
    select: function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);

        if(val == "2008"){
             $(this).find("option:eq(1)").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $(this).find("option:eq(1)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        // must call this to reflect the change
        $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
    }
});
```

Comment: Also it has some kind of a documentation: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I was having trouble finding the documentation since this appears to be a pre-release component.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I made some minor changed to your code (deleted the alert and changed $this into #c2. I am a step closer thanks to your help, but whatever option i select it always disables the field. The code is in the topic. [edit] Sorry i was to quick.. i forgot to change a 'this'. I'll try if everything works now.

Comment: Is #c2 another menu? I assumed you were changing options in a single menu based on the selection in the same menu. You can fork the jsfiddle I created if you want to add your actual markup.

Comment: Yes #c2 is another menu. It works in the demo file, but i can't get it to work in the real file.. I keep on trying. Can i come back here and ask another question about this issue later?

Comment: Sure. If you open a new question, just post a link here in the comments so I'll see it.

Comment: Just to make sure:

* Yes, its a pre-release, coming (hopefully with jQuery UI 1.11)
* Yes, you need to change the native select and call refresh after that
* Please note: there is a legacy version with different API and functionality, see https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#year").enableSelection();
```

May be this helps you

Comment: this method allow you to do selection